# Real bad with directory/file path

Tags: html

I'm having trouble creating path for my image. I can't get it right and very frustrated.
I'm using Linux and here is the directory I'm working with:

My working folder is called :WebSec
Unlike in windows, WebSec is not under inetpub/www/WebSec but it is under:
      /home/space/users/www/WebSec

My image folder is also under the same dir:
       /home/space/users/www/images

Under my WebSec, I have many folders and files:
       WebSec
       ----Login Folder
       ----Form Folder
       ----Report Folder
       ----Registration Folder, etc
       index.cfm
       header.cfm
       footer.cfm
    etc

Within my Header I have something like this:
    img src="/images/home.jpg border="0" 
    but this image don't show up on the page.
    The home.jpg image is there under /home/space/users/www/images
    I did: img src="../images/home.jpg border="0" did not work
    I did: img src="./images/home.jpg border="0"  did not work
    I did: img src="./../images/home.jpg border="0" also did not work 
    I can't do img src="images/home.jpg border="0" because my images folder is not under
    WebSec

Comment: "I can't do img src="images/home.jpg border="0" because my images folder is not under WebSec?" Really? It´s in the same level, this should be the correct one path. If it doesn´t working, do you have image called `home.jpg`?

Comment: Its not in the same lavel. images folder is up from the root.

Comment: Anyway, i'm not sure how Cold Fusion works, but possibly if WebSec is your root might not be able to go up the root, or maybe the permissions to images folder are not set correctly.

Comment: There's a missing `"` in `img src="../images/home.jpg border="0"` - is that really in your code or was it just a typo when posting here?

Comment: Surreal, that is my miskate, it is a typo. I just checked, the quotes are there: img src="/images/alogo.jpg" border="0"

Comment: Thank you guys, I moved all images to image folder under WebSec and it looks like I'm good for now.

Comment: Don't forget to close this question. If the solution is something that will help others, post it as an "answer". Otherwise, just delete the thread.